# How to perform RACH attacks on GSM mobile networks?

Tags: vulnerability, gsm

I am studying various vulnerabilities on GSM networks and would like to know what hardware and software are needed to test such vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

A full-duplex software defined radio would be useful - it would allow you to send any GSM packet you want, even malformed ones which you won't be able to send with off-the-shelf GSM hardware.

On the software side you can always use custom code to generate your GSM frames, but you can have a look at [OpenBTS](http://openbts.org) and [OsmocomBB](https://osmocom.org/projects/baseband) for ready-to-use open source code that handles the GSM protocol. [GNU Radio](http://gnuradio.org/) has a [module](https://github.com/ptrkrysik/gr-gsm) for GSM as well. Wireshark can display captured GSM frames.